# iOS: Why [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO] is changing my class address?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, uiviewcontroller, setuserinteractionenabled

I use that property in a class:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NameOfMyClass* form;
```

When I use that code in my 
main function:
form = formToSend;

```
//CHECK MANDATORIES
BOOL validMandatories = (0 != [self checkMandatoryFieldsWithForm:form withTableView:self.tableView withForm:self.formController]);

if (validMandatories)
{
    [self submitRegistrationForm];
}
```

and that code in the sub function:

```
- (void)submitRegistrationForm
{
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];=> change the form address
    ....

}
```

It changes the address of the form class.
Before the [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]

```
Printing description of self->form:
<RegistrationForm_Renault_Control_Adagio: 0x7f81bf8a0200>
```

After the [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]

```
Printing description of self->form:
<RegistrationForm_Renault_Control_Adagio: 0x7f81c092b600>
```

**My solution to avoid the problem, but I would even like to understand why...**

```
NameOfMyClass* formTemp = form; 
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
form = formTemp;
```

Any explanations?

Comment: Look's like you have undefined behavior. Try to run Product->Analyze. Check address sanitizer and undefined behavior sanitizer options.

Comment: It definitely is not your `setUserInteractionEnabled` code. Please show us the three lines: print address, setUserInteraction, print address again